Extract epoch from column of timestamps in Postgres
What is the syntax to get the epoch from a timestamp column with time zone.
I can use with time zone in the following way and it works as expected
select extract(epoch from timestamp with time zone '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 +00') ;

returns 0
select extract(epoch from timestamp with time zone '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 -0500') ;

returns 18000.000000
Great!
But this returns the same epoch for both:
select extract(epoch from ts ) 
from(
    select to_timestamp(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd h24:mi:ss') ts
    from (
        select unnest (array[
        '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 +00',
        '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 -0500'
        ]) ts
    )
);

18000.000000
18000.000000

Where do I put the with time zone when I am extracting the epoch for a column of timestamps?
I have tried the following with no success:

epoch from ts with time zone --fails SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "with"
epoch from ts::timestamp with time zone -- runs, but gives the same values for both


That is because this to_timestamp(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd h24:mi:ss') is turning them into the  same timestamp. One that has been adjusted to the server time zone. There is no need for the to_timestamp just do ... select ts::timestamptz ts ....

In PostgreSQL, when you convert a text timestamp to a timestamp with time zone, the conversion will use the current time zone setting unless you explicitly specify the time zone in the conversion.
However, since your timestamps already include the time zone information, you can directly cast them to timestamptz without using to_timestamp:
SELECT extract(epoch FROM ts::timestamptz) 
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY[
        '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 +00',
        '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 -0500'
    ]) AS ts
) subquery;

This will correctly interpret the time zone information included in the timestamps and provide the correct epoch values.
0.000000
18000.000000

Explanation:
The first timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 +00' corresponds to epoch 0.
The second timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 -0500' is 5 hours behind UTC, which corresponds to an epoch of 18000 seconds.

With a different format that includes time zone formatting codes, your query would have worked:
to_timestamp(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZHTZM')


This might be what you're looking for
select extract(epoch from ts) 
from(
  select ts::TIMESTAMPTZ at time zone 'UTC' ts
   from (
       select unnest (array[
       '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+00',
       '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000-0500'
       ]) ts
   ) a
) b;

From your query; the timezone needs to be identified through the cast first before using the epoch.

The at time zone 'UTC' isn't necessary.

Yes, it is not necessary indeed. It would only be useful to demonstrate if the timezone is formatted properly in this case.

When given a timestamptz on input, at time zone shifts it and strips the timezone from it. The ::timestamptz in your example already demonstrates the validity of the offset seen in the values - whether you strip that or not, its correctly aligned and one ends up 0s from the epoch, the other 5h, as per the +00 and -0500.
